# Holes appear in object mode but not in edit mode

Tags: rendering, edit-mode

As I was working on making a rendering better I change some settings on blender and ended up with holes in my object that do no appear in edit mode. Increasing subdivisions helps but does not clear it, any ideas?[image][image]

Comment: Can you add screenshots to your question? With the current description it's very hard to tell what happens.

Comment: yeah sorry was meant to but forgot, here they are. Yeah I cant really remember what I changed, I was just messing about really.

Comment: The issue is that the vertex you have selected is not connected to several faces around it. You need to fix your topology. you can see that things are going wrong because the orange line extends far beyond the neighboring vertex, indicating that they are not connected.